# C# Special Characters in String Crashing Program

Tags: c#, string

I have a slight problem with a path:

```
"D:\\Music\\DJ Ti%C3%ABsto\\Tiesto\\Adagio For Strings (Spirit of London).mp3"
"D:\\Music\\Dj Tiësto\\Tiesto\\Adagio For Strings (Spirit of London).mp3"
```

Currently, when it sends that path to my Audio Library, it cannot open the path. (the reason for it crashing is trying to assign a -1 to a trackbar...but it's irrelevant).

So I'm wondering, is there anyway to prevent C# from switching special characters with %[code]? I've done a .Replace for "[" and "]", but I rather not have to look up every single special character, and add a line of code to prevent it. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: How did you end up with the encoded string in the first place?

Comment: Yes, if you're URI-encoding local file paths like that, you're doing something wrong.  A lot of Microsoft libraries will accept local paths when a URI is expected, but even Microsoft will tell you you're not supposed to do that.  And the percent encoding should only be used with URIs, not local paths.  (For those, use the Unicode string directly -- all the .NET file-handling stuff uses wide chars, so it shouldn't have any trouble with non-ASCII characters.)

Comment: @Daniel: Precisely, I think `Mike` should look beyond this fixing issue and find out how in the first place the string ended up encoded.

Comment: Ah, if only there was a "Spirit of London" remix of that track.  Good 'ole KaZaA making up filenames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`Uri.UnescapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx).

By the way, when putting paths in strings, you can put an `@` sign before the string to tell the compiler not to process escape codes, like this: `@"D:\Music\DJ Tiësto\Tiesto\Adagio For Strings (Spirit of London).mp3"`.  This way, you don't need to double up every backslash.